# Magento1.8 - What is the best script for creating order?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Iam new in magento , i want to create script for creating orders
i have searched for scripts alot and i get this:

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

    // for guesr orders only:
    $quote->setCustomerEmail('customer@example.com');

// add product(s)
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(431);
$buyInfo = array(
    'qty' => 1,
    // custom option id => value id
    // or
    // configurable attribute id => value id
);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));

$addressData = array(
    'firstname' => 'Test',
    'lastname' => 'Test',
    'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
    'city' => 'Somewhere',
    'postcode' => '123456',
    'telephone' => '123456',
    'country_id' => 'SA',

);

$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')
            ->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');

$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'cashondelivery'));

$quote->collectTotals()->save();

$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();

printf("Created order %s\n", $order->getIncrementId());
?>
```

But when i run this script it give me error "page isn’t working".

Can you please helping me fixing this or give me script that create orders.

Note "i run this script through "www.site.com/createorder.php"

Thanks

Comment: attach screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

I tried this once and it works :

```
<?php
include '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
// Need for start the session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
try {

    $product_ids = array(
         $_GET['product_id_1'],
        $_GET['product_id_2'],
         $_GET['product_id_3'],
         $_GET['product_id_4'] 
        );  
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
    {
        addToCart($product_ids[$i]);
    } 
    /*addToCart($product_id_1); */

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Product added successfully');
    header('Location: ' .Mage::getBaseURl(). 'checkout/cart/');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
function addToCart($product_id)
{
    $qty = '1';
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    $cart->save();
    return true;
}
?>
```

The link should be given four parameters in the form of product_id_1 and so on. You can change that accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your code
but i have problem when i run the code through: 
https://uae.arabianoud.com/create/doorder.php
it give me  
"The product could not be found."
even the product id is right
i added product id like this: 
    try {
    $product_ids = array(
         $_GET['product_id_122'],
        $_GET['product_id_48'],
         $_GET['product_id_50'],
         $_GET['product_id_49'] 
        );  
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
    {
        addToCart($product_ids[$i]);
    } 

also can you please tell me how can i update the customer details and shipping details

Comment: this won't work obviously, the code will go like this : $_GET['122'] instead of $_GET['product_id_122'] and so on, let me know if this works for you